# MFMailcomposeviewcontroller send button is disabled

Tags: ios, swift, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Has anyone faced an issue where the `MFMailcomposeviewcontroller` send button is disabled/grayed out? The cancel button works perfectly fine.

It seems like a new bug?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the Simulator? Testing mail needs to be done on a device.

Comment: I've done it on a device. But it works on my iPhone 6 and not on my iPhone 7

Comment: That's because your device is not configured to send emails. First set up an email account on your device and then try again

Comment: @Michael Nopes on Simulator, `canSendEmail` returns false so you can never even get the dialogue of email composer to open on simulator without running into a crash. The fact that he can present the dialogue tells us that he is running it on a device, albeit on a device which doesn't have an email account enabled

Comment: Perhaps the "to" or "from" field is empty. Can't send an email until both are filled in.

Answer (score 33):

This could happen in case native Mail application is removed from iPhone (allowed starting from iOS 10). In this case system Setting missing "Mail" setting item and system probably cannot get configuration of default email account.

At the same moment `MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail()` return `true`, so I did not find any solution to solve this case.

Comment: I have the same issue, any solution?

Comment: Yes, I had same issue. MAIL app was not installed in my iPhone. After installing the Mail App. Send buttton get enabled.

Comment: Yes still happens on 11.4

Comment: Happening with me even with latest ios 12.1

Comment: Still getting the same issue in iOS 13.3.1

Comment: So if this is the cuase, then what is the solution. It should obviously work to use other mail applications as well. What's the workaround?

Comment: Still seeing this on iOS 14.6.

Answer (score 1):

Getting same issue and spent few hours to find out the solution and working fine now.

1)check default **"Mail"** app of your ios device is **uninstall**
or
2)already exist but offload this app from setting that time showing icon like attached image than just **install** app again and solve the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Mail App is installed in your device.